# Angular 2 Remove Class on another element (same template)

Tags: angular

Does anyone know how to remove the class of an element with (click) from another element in the same template?

```
<button (click)="#options.classList.remove("hideMe")('hideMe')" class="mobile-only">
        Show options
</button>

<div #options id="optionsDiv" class="hideMe">
        ...
</div>
```

Comment: `(click)="options.classList.remove('hideMe')"` but would be better to use solution that JB Nizet said below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use binding:

In the component:

```
public hideMeClassPresent = true;
```

In the template:

```
<button (click)="hideMeClassPresent = false" class="mobile-only">
    Show options
</button>

<div id="optionsDiv" [class.hideMe]="hideMeClassPresent">
    ...
</div>
```

That's the basic angular principle: you don't do DOM manipulation. You modify the model, and the template generates HTML based on the model.

Comment: Thanks for the this! : )